# Angular2 model driven form - values not changing

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm struggling with a model driven form I'm building in angular2. What's confusing me is that my selects are working perfectly fine and updating as they should. input elements however, aren't.

HTML:

```
  <form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addLineitem(f)">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <label for="article_no">Article</label>
        <select formControlName="article_no" class="form-control" id="article_no">
          <option *ngFor="let article of articles" [ngValue]="article.ArticleNo">{{article.ArticleNo}}: {{article.ArticleName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="article_groups">Article Group</label>
        <select formControlName="article_groups" id="article_groups" class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let group of articleGroups" [ngValue]="group.MainGroupNo">{{group.MainGroupNo}}: {{group.ArticleGroupName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" FormControlName="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
      <input FormControlName="comments" id="comments" class="form-control">
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="form.controls.comments.errors">A block of help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend beyond one line.</span>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="minutes">Minutes</label>
      <input type="number" FormControlName="minutes" id="minutes" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

TS:

```
constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = this._fb.group({
      article_no: [0, Validators.required],
      article_groups: [1],
      quantity: [0, Validators.required],
      comments: [],
      minutes: [0, Validators.required]
    })

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(values => { // Triggers on both select controls, not on quantity,comments or minutes-control.
      console.log(values);
    })

  }
```

Any suggestions on where I'm messing up? I've been trying various methods, and while I could be lazy and use NgModel, I'd rather avoid that, as it seems.. redundant. I followed the guide @ http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html, and I honestly can't see anywhere my code differs (outside of var names etc, of course).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `FormBuilder` class, you use the model-driven approach and not the template-driven one.

Moreover with old forms (and template-driven approach), you need to leverage the `ngControl` directive:

```
<input ngControl="comments" id="comments"
       class="form-control" #comments="ngForm">
```

With model-driven approach (`FormBuilder`), you use the `ngFormControl` one:

```
<input ngFormControl="form.controls.comments"
       id="comments" class="form-control" #comments="ngForm">
```

Comment: I'm using the new forms api (import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms') - ngFormControl was used in the old forms I believe?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah never mind - I used FormControlName instead of formControlName (note the capitalization). Fml.